# Trouble creating parent-child relationship between two database tables using php codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have two databases tables called article_category and article_case. They are supposed to be combined in a webpage as below:

Article category[title]
Article category[description]
Article case[title]
Article case[contents]
Article case[title]
Article case[contents]

This should repeat itself using foreach until all article categories are populated on the page.
Each article_case will also use foreach, but it has to respect its 'category_id' value which matches the 'id' in article_category .

I'm having trouble filtering the article_case table so that it only picks up rows from its parent 'category_id'.

This is my current php code (which only makes an array of each table):

```
$this->db->select( "id,title,description" );
$this->db->from( 'article_category' );
$query_article_category = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$query = $this->db->query( $query_sustainability_category . 'ORDER BY sort ASC ' );
foreach ($query->result_array() as $val) {
        $data['article_category_posts'][$val['id']] = $val;}

$this->db->select( "id,category_id,title,contents" );
$this->db->from( 'article_case' );
$query_article_case = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$query = $this->db->query( $query_article_case);
$data[ 'article_cases' ] = $query->result_array();
```

And here is my html:

```
    <?php foreach ($article_category_posts as $key => $val) { ?>
<section>
   <h2><?php echo $val['title']; ?></h2>
   <p><?php echo $val['description']; ?></p>
</section>
<?php foreach ($article_cases as $key => $val) { ?>
<section>
   <h3><?php echo $val['title']; ?></h3>
   <p><?php echo $val['contents']; ?></p>
</section>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

The current setup will input all article_cases disregarding the category_id.
How can I use foreach while assigning each article_case to their respective article_cateogry?

Comment: Be careful with terminology: what you are calling a "database" is actually a "table" (or "database table" if you need to distinguish from some other meaning of "table") - the database is the thing that holds _all_ the tables. In this case, it's clear what you mean from context, but making sure to know the right terms will avoid people misunderstanding you, and help you find existing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use a query to get all the records of `article_case` with related `article_category`.
- group the query result by `category_id`.

  ```
   $this->db->select("cat.title,cat.description,case.category_id, 
    case.title AS case_title, case.contents" );
   $this->db->from( 'article_category cat');
   $this->db->join('article_case case','case.category_id=cat.id');
   $result=$this->db->get()->result_array();

   $result_group = array_group_by($result, 'category_id');
  ```
- array group by function

  ```
   function array_group_by(array $array, $key)
   {
       if (!is_string($key) && !is_int($key) && !is_float($key) && !is_callable($key)) {
           trigger_error('array_group_by(): The key should be a string, an integer, or a callback', E_USER_ERROR);

           return NULL;
       }
       $func = (is_callable($key) ? $key : NULL);
       $_key = $key;
       // Load the new array, splitting by the target key
       $grouped = [];
       foreach ($array as $value) {
           if (is_callable($func)) {
               $key = call_user_func($func, $value);
           } elseif (is_object($value) && isset($value->{$_key})) {
               $key = $value->{$_key};
           } elseif (isset($value[$_key])) {
               $key = $value[$_key];
           } else {
               continue;
           }
           $grouped[$key][] = $value;
       }
       // Recursively build a nested grouping if more parameters are supplied
       // Each grouped array value is grouped according to the next sequential key
       if (func_num_args() > 2) {
           $args = func_get_args();
           foreach ($grouped as $key => $value) {
               $params = array_merge([$value], array_slice($args, 2, func_num_args()));
               $grouped[$key] = call_user_func_array('array_group_by', $params);
           }
       }

       return $grouped;
   }
  ```
- in view you can show as below

  ```
   <?php foreach ($result_group as $key => $cat_result) { ?>
     <section>
       <h2><?php echo $cat_result[0]['title']; ?></h2>
       <p><?php echo $cat_result[0]['description']; ?></p>
       <div class="box-bd-doted">
     </section>
     <?php foreach ($cat_result as $key => $val) { ?>
       <section>
         <h3 style="color:red"><?php echo $val['case_title']; ?></h3>
         <p><?php echo $val['contents']; ?></p>
       </section>
     <?php } 
   }
   ?>
  ```

Comment: array_group_by gives an undefined function error. Is it a custom function I have to install?

Comment: sorry, now i have added the function to answer above please check.

Answer (score 1):

This would generate unnecessary amount of queries to the DB server.

The rly basic approach would be:

- select all categories (as you have) `SELECT * FORM a_category`
- for each category select cases `SELECT * FROM a_case WHERE category_id = {$category['id']}`

The second one is to combine the categories and cases right in the query with join and adjust the resulting data in php:

```sql
SELECT cat.title, cat.description, case.id AS case_id, case.category_id, case.title, case.content
FROM a_case case
INNER JOIN a_category cat ON cat.id = case.category_id
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm having trouble joining the tables though. On my code INNER JOIN is joining the original tables without the WHERE attributes. How do I select the filtered results and join them?

I've created two queries, one from the results of `SELECT * FORM a_category` ($query1) , and one from `SELECT * FROM a_case WHERE category_id = {$category['id']}` ($query2) .

How can I join those two queries?